# Checking if strings are the same c++

Tags: c++, string, compare

For my case, I have to check if 2 strings are the same. The probelm I'm getting, is that No matter what I input, I'm getting a true value regardless of what I put in.

```
bool Dictionary::checkIfWordExists(string input){
for(int counter=0;counter<234;counter++){
    if(input.compare(getWordFromDictionary(counter))){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;}
```

For testing purposes I used a do loop like this to type in stuff to test in comparison to the dictionary.txt file that I loaded.

```
do{
    cout<<"enter something you sexy beast"<<endl;
    string test;
    cin>>test;
    if(loadedDictionary.checkIfWordExists(test)){
        cout<<"yes"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"no"<<endl;
    }
}while(true);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's because compare actually returns `0` when the strings are equal. If the strings are not equal, it will return a value higher or lower and the if will evaluate to true, as you are seeing.

It is common in languages like Java and C# to use methods like `equals` to compare non-primitives, but in C++ it is preferably to just use `==`.

Comment: Thanks man... I feel so retarded when my problems are that simple. Ahaha

Comment: I think it's worth noting that using the `==` operator would be more clear and correct than then `compare()` function.

Answer (score 1):

There should be an `operator==` for `std::string` available for a more natural feeling comparison.

```
if(input == getWordFromDictionary(counter)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly compare the result of `compare` with `0`. Here is what the return values mean:

0   => The compared strings are equal

<0  => Either the value of the first character that does not match is lower in the 
       compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is 
       shorter.

>0  => Either the value of the first character that does not match is greater in the 
        compared string, or all compared characters match but the compared string is 
        longer.

See here for the detailed explanation on [std::string::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).